# Unable to email in HTML format.

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send email in HTML format. It is working for text/plain. But when i set content type to text/html mail is not being transported(no exception is being thrown but i don't get email as well).
Following is my code.

```
public void postMail() throws Exception {
            boolean debug = false;

            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpServer);
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", smtpServerPort);
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback","false");
            lgr.debug(lgr.isDebugEnabled()?"SMTP Server --->" + smtpServer : null);
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
            session.setDebug(debug);

            Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

            InternetAddress addressFrom = new InternetAddress(from);
            msg.setFrom(addressFrom);
            // Here is some logic to add TO and CC and BCC
            msg.setSubject(subject);
            //    writer.println("Subject : " + subject);
            lgr.debug(lgr.isDebugEnabled()?"Subject : " + subject : null);
            msg.setContent(message, "text/html");
            Transport.send(msg);
            lgr.info(lgr.isInfoEnabled() ?"Mail sent": null);
}
```

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you place some sample mail content that you tried to pass on email..

Comment: Following is content <HTML>
<BODY>
<B>Hello All,</B> 

Cache refreshed successfully at [Mon Apr 01 19:25:41 PKT 2013].</BR>

It is to be noted that cache will be refreshed again after approximately [100] minute(s). </BR>

Please note this is an informative message and system is up and running.</BR>
</BODY>
</HTML>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Get rid of the socket factory stuff](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes), you don't need it.

When you set debug to true, do you see any errors in the debug output?  Or is your mail server accepting the message without complaint?  If no errors, then most likely the problem is that the recipient's mail server thinks your message is spam, although that seems unlikely with your simple test message.

Have you tried sending to different recipients, especially different recipients using different mail servers?  It would be useful to figure out if the problem is with the recipient's mail server or with the mail server you're using for sending.

Comment: Thanks for  the directions. I have tried them and changing from and to addresses seems to work. Is there an issue with this ?

Comment: It sounds like one of the mail servers is losing your message, probably because it thinks it's spam.  Since I don't know exactly what you tested, I can't tell you which mail server is likely at fault.  If you can figure it out, you might want to contact the mail server administrator.

Comment: You are right@Bill. Mail server was marking it spam and eventually discarding that mail.It was happening in case to and from was same address. But in case of different to and from everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue some times back. I found that the issue was with the html content containing single quotes.

As a test try to send a (simple word)/(simple html without quotes at all) as message using text/html format. If that works you can probably modify your html message to contain only double quotes.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Tried following without any luck<HTML><BODY><B>Hello All,</B></BODY></HTML>